# What are the bumpy parts around the spindle of some pedals?

Tags: pedals, tools

Does anybody know what the bumpy part near the threads of this pedal are for? They look like they might fit a special wrench, but I can't find any that would fit.

[image: Bumpy-spindled-pedal]

I feel like I must be missing something, and that I've seen these bumps around, but never understood their purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 'official' tool that engages with that bumpy collar is the Shimano TL-PD-40 bearing shaft removal tool. It's a plastic tool designed to be used with a larger wrench, or a vice. Here's a pic: 
[TL-PD-40](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/311FAvSyLeL._SX300_.jpg)

If you're interested in servicing your pedals using this tool and others, here's a how-to from Park Tool: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/spd-pedal-overhaul

Answer (score 2):

The bumpy part unscrews. That's how you get to the bearings, I believe. They make special tools that fit over it - if you can't find that, and you don't care about the bumpy part looking pretty, you can just use pliers.